# Catch copy/paste of empty text on Windows from AutoHotKey script

Tags: windows, copy-paste, autohotkey

By default on Windows, when copying text, it gets put in the clipboard. But when attempting to copy *empty* text, the clipboard is untouched. For example, selecting no text in your editor, then hitting `ctrl+c`, will cause no change in the clipboard.

Problem is, I need to catch this event with AutoHotKey. Since the clipboard is unchanged, I have no idea how to do this cleanly (without a timeout, that is).

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

**Edit:** To clarify, I'm sending the ctrl+c from within AutoHotKey. I'm doing so to tell if any text is selected, i.e., I'm sending ctrl+c, then checking if any text was copied to the clipboard or not. Problem is, if no text is selected, the clipboard handlers for AutoHotKey never get called, forcing me to use a timeout, which isn't good practice.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I did. Since the clipboard is a variable in AutoHotkey, you can check to see if it is empty. I first cleared the clipboard, send control+c, then see if the clipboard is still empty. You can temporarily move the current clipboard to a temporary place first if you want.

```
ClipSaved := ClipboardAll
Clipboard =     ; empties the clipboard
Send ^+{Left}   ;  I just used highlight left to select text, you can replace this with
             ; whatever your program uses to select an input.
Send ^c         ; attempt to copy text
If Clipboard =  ;  checks to see if clipboard is empty
{
    break  ; Put what you want to do if the clipboard is empty, I used break to stop a loop
}
Clipboard := ClipSaved  ; puts the original clipboard contents back
```

I was searching text from an open document in which the user can choose a forward or backward direction. When going backwards, it would get stuck in a loop at the beginning of the document. I set a loop limit to keep it from being an infinite loop, but it still wasted time having to wait for the loop to finish. I used the break function to end the loop if the clipboard was empty.

To give credit where credit is due, I got the inspiration from another post which had other tood tips. It posted you can check for a blank variable with this script.
http://www.autohotkey.net/~deleyd/xprxmp/autohotkey_expression_examples.htm#J
 v := ""

```
If v =
    MsgBox v = ""

If (v = "")
    MsgBox v = ""
```

From the AutoHotkey documentation website I found out how to temporarily store and replace the clipboard content. http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Clipboard.htm

```
ClipSaved := ClipboardAll   ; Save the entire clipboard to a variable of your choice.
    ;... here make temporary use of the clipboard, such as for pasting Unicode text via    Transform Unicode ...
Clipboard := ClipSaved   ; Restore the original clipboard. Note the use of Clipboard    (not ClipboardAll).
ClipSaved =   ; Free the memory in case the clipboard was very large.
```

Hope this helps.
Samuel

Comment: The problem is that Ctrl+C takes time to work. It's entirely possible for no text to appear in the Clipboard variable when you check it, but for it to appear a few seconds after. How do you get around that?

Answer (score 2):

Here's the solution I currently use. Basically, it comes down to sending `ctrl+c`, waiting a certain timeout, then seeing if text was actually copied. If it wasn't, I know there is not selection.

There is no way, afaik, to avoid waiting a timeout, since Windows takes a certain time to perform the `copy` operation. I set the timeout to 0.15 seconds, so it isn't too bad.

Here's the function I use whenever I want to grab the contents of the clipboard, or check if it's empty. I always call this function first:

```
clipped_text :=
clip_empty := false
ClipSaved =
is_clipped := false

clip_speed := 0.15

Clip() {
    global ClipSaved
    global clip_empty
    global clipped_text
    global is_clipped
    global clip_speed

    if (!is_clipped) {
        ClipSaved := ClipboardAll   ; Save the entire clipboard to a variable of your choice.
        ; msgbox % ClipSaved
        is_clipped := true
    }

    clipboard = ; Empty the clipboard

    Send ^{c}
    ClipWait clip_speed

    if (ErrorLevel = 1)
    {
        clip_empty := false
    }
    else
    {
        clip_empty := true
        clipped_text := clipboard
    }
}
```

And I use this function to actually get the contents of the clipboard or check if it's empty:

```
IsTextSelected() {
    global ClipSaved
    global clip_empty
    global clipped_text

    if (clip_empty == true) {
        return true
    }
    else {
        return false
    }
}
```

To get the contents of the clipboard I just look at the clipped_text variable.

After performing a "Clip()" operation, I always call the following function to restore the clipboard (this function is called *once* for multiple calls of `Clip()`):

```
UnClip() {
    global ClipSaved
    global clip_empty
    global clipped_text
    global is_clipped

    is_clipped := false
    Clipboard := ClipSaved
    ClipSaved =
}
```

Answer (score 2):

While not an actual answer to this question, a google search might lead you here if you are **looking for a way to catch text on paste and modify it before pasting**.

Here's the script which eliminates whitespace from text pasted from clipboard on <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>:

```
~^v::
Trimmed := RegExReplace(Clipboard, "^\s+", "")
Trimmed := RegExReplace(Trimmed, "\s+$", "")
Clipboard = %Trimmed%
SendInput ^v
return
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should hotkey the Ctrl + C instead, that way any time that hotkey is pressed you will know.

You might want to make sure to send the normal Ctrl + C action to windows so you can copy.
consider this example:

```
~^c::
msgbox, % "Clipboard Changed even if you didnt copy anything"
        . "(...not really but you tried at least)"
return
```

That message will fire up every time you press Ctrl + C even if you didnt copy anything to the clipboard. At the same time you will be sending the native function of Ctrl + C to windows so your clipboard WILL change if you copied something.

From the help file:

> **~**: When the hotkey fires, its key's native function will not be blocked (hidden from the system).

You might want to also have an `onClipboardChange` to check when the clipboard really changed.

Comment: The problem is, I'm programatically sending the ctrl+c, and I want to see if text is captured. I'm using it to check programatically if there is a selection (i.e., is text selected right now, or not). So this solution doesn't help me, since I already know the ctrl+c is being sent, since I'm the one sending it! Thanks for the creative idea though, I'll edit the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a solution. Set aside current clipboard, then copy. Compare what you have copied to an empty string.. if it's equal, then something was copied; otherwise, nothing was copied. At then, restore the clipboard to what you saved. Here is a code sample demonstrating the principle.

```
^#x::
   ClipSaved := ClipboardAll   ; Save the entire clipboard to a variable of your choice.
   ; ... here make temporary use of the clipboard, such as for pasting Unicode text via Transform Unicode ...
   Clipboard := ; Clear the clipboard
   Send, {CTRLDOWN}c{CTRLUP}
   if (Clipboard = "") {
      Send, you copied nothing
   } else {
      Send, you copied something
   }
   Clipboard := ClipSaved   ; Restore the original clipboard. Note the use of Clipboard (not ClipboardAll).
   ClipSaved =   ; Free the memory in case the clipboard was very large.
return
```

Actually, I was hoping that there is another way to simply test if the cursor is currently selecting anything. I have asked this question on the AutoHotkey forums (http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/posting.php?mode=reply&t=69468), but until or if there is a better answer, I will use the above method.

Comment: That won't work. The problem is, "ctrl+c" takes time to work. In your code, after doing the "Send, {CTRLDOWN}c{CTRLUP}", you're right away checking the clipboard. But the whole problem is that after sending the "ctrl+c", you're supposed to wait a certain timeout to give Windows time to actually perform the ctrl+c operation. You'll run into edge cases where text *is* selected, but you won't recognize it. I'm adding a new answer now with what I currently do.

Comment: "That won't work". It does work. I will keep timeout in mind, but I have been using this a lot in the past few days and have not seen the issue you describe yet.

Comment: That's odd. I've seen the issue happen. For example, I tried creating a command that copies the text, adds quote marks around it, then pastes it back. Without a timeout, when a large amount of text is selected, sometimes it will fail to grab the text. This is dependent on the speed of your computer at the moment. So either you haven't run into it yet, or I have a bug.

Comment: I think it's to do with how fast the pc can copy - I have only used this on relatively small amounts of text. I use it in a script for helping with HTML elements..

Answer (score 0):

Script for babylon (Middle Mouse Key for firefox):

```
MButton::
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
send {LButton}{LButton}
Send ^c
sleep, 100
send {F10}
sleep, 100
SendInput {Raw}%clipboard%
send {enter}
Return
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - I would send the copy command, but it wouldn't copy anything.  I tried working with timers to no avail.

Here is what I ended up doing (trying different modes):

```
thisclipboard := clipboard . a_now  ;add NOW so that it won't possibly be the same as the contents of the clipboard
    sendplay,^c
    if(clipboard == thisclipboard){
        sendinput,^c
    }
    if(clipboard == thisclipboard){
        send,^c
    }
```